# Laravel is unable to locate user factory

Tags: laravel

I'm building some tests in Laravel and I'm getting a very persistent error: `InvalidArgumentException: Unable to locate factory for [App\Models\User].`

The `User` class and `UserFactory` both exist and I believe I've used the correct namespacing. I have tried running `composer dump autoload` and to clear the `cache` and `config` but this has not worked.

My feature test:

```
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithFaker;
use Tests\TestCase;

class ProjectsTest extends TestCase
{
    use WithFaker, RefreshDatabase;

    /** @test */
    public function only_authenticated_users_can_create_projects()
    {
        $attributes = factory('App\Models\Project')->raw();
        $this->post('/projects', $attributes)->assertRedirect('login');
    }
}
```

This is the ProjectFactory:

```
<?php

use Faker\Generator as Faker;

$factory->define(App\Models\Project::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'title' => $faker->sentence,
        'description' => $faker->paragraph,
        'owner_id' => function () {
            return factory(App\Models\User::class)->create()->id;
        },
    ];
});
```

And here's the UserFactory:

```
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class UserFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * The name of the factory's corresponding model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $model = User::class;

    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'name' => $this->faker->name,
            'email' => $this->faker->unique()->safeEmail,
            'email_verified_at' => now(),
            'password' => '$2y$10$92IXUNpkjO0rOQ5byMi.Ye4oKoEa3Ro9llC/.og/at2.uheWG/igi', // password
            'remember_token' => Str::random(10),
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your `UserFactory` class, I assume you are using Laravel 8.

The new way to [call factories in Laravel 8](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database-testing#using-factories) is

```
$user = User::factory()->create();
```

instead of the old way

```
$user = factory(User::class)->create();
```

I think you mixed Laravel 8 and 7 syntax in your `ProjectFactory`. I would recommend to delete your `ProjectFactory`  and recreate it on Laravel 8 basis with the PHP artisan command: `php artisan make:factory ProjectFactory`.
Then you would call the factory like this:

```
$project = Project::factory()->create();
```

Make sure your Project model uses the `hasFactory;` trait for this to work.

Comment: What if I want to continue using the old way? I've already installed legacy factory

Answer (score 0):

In my case I'd forgotten to change namespace in UserFactory file after moving the User model to Models directory.